# Azure migration from Classic to ARM

Tags: azure, migration, vnet

I am currently trying to migrate my Azure VNET and VM's to Azure ARM.

I have ran the following part of the Powershell Script I am using:

```
Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Validate -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName).validationmessages
```

And amongst other error relating to Endpoints, Backup services and Boot Diagnosis I get this error:

> ResourceType       : VirtualNetwork
>
> ResourceName       : *Vnet Name*
>
> Category           : Error
>
> Message            : Migration of virtual network: *Vnet Name* failed
>   as the address prefix *LocalSite Subnet* of local network site 
>                        *Local Site Name* is invalid. Please fix the network configuration before trying to migrate.

I'm not sure why I am getting these errors? I have 5 local sites connected to the S2S route-based VPN and get this error for 3 sites, the other 2 sites dont come up in the errors even though they seem to be no different.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the migration flag certain address space as invalid, you going to have to remove site, migrate and readd site after migration.